# BadMethodCallException with eager loading in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I have two models `User.php` and `Blog.php` and the content,

Model ***User.php***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    //-----
    public function blogs()
    {
       return $this->has_many('Blog');
    }
    //----
```

Model ***Blog.php***

```
<?php

class Blog extends Eloquent {

   protected $guarded = array();

   public static $rules = array();

   public function author()
   {
     return $this->belongs_to('User', 'author_id');
   }
}
```

The Controller, ***BlogsController.php***

```
<?php

class BlogsController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
           $posts = Blog::with('author')->get();

           return Response::json(array(
              'status'   => 'success',
              'message'  => 'Posts successfully loaded!',
              'posts'    => $posts->toArray()),
              200
       );
    }
    //-----
```

The ***blogs schema***,

```
Schema::create('blogs', function(Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('title');
     $table->text('body');
     $table->integer('author_id');
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->softDeletes();
});
```

And the ***users schema***,

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->integer('id', true);
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('username')->unique();
   $table->string('email')->unique();
   $table->string('password');
   $table->timestamps();
   $table->softDeletes();
});
```

When I call `Blog::with('author')->get();` from `BlogsController`, I am getting this error:-

```
"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::belongs_to()"
```

And when I change `Blog::with('author')->get();` to `Blog::with('author')->all();`, the error become:-

```
"type":"BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::all()"
```

I am using latest update for Laravel 4. What is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to love and hate this answer, change `belongs_to` to `belongsTo`. Same goes for `has_many` to `hasMany` and `has_one` to `hasOne`.

Laravel 4 moved to using camel case for methods. Your method not being found on the eloquent model, it falls back to calling it on the query builder, laravel does this to allow short cutting to methods like `select()` and `where()`.

The second error you were getting, when using `all()`, is because `all()` is a static method defined on eloquent and does not work with eager loading. `get()` is effectively the same thing as `all()`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have referred out-dated code from http://codehappy.daylerees.com/the-blog-tutorial. Thanks for quick response.